how to do autosave on editvertex ? because i dont want user to save all the time when he/she edits
Just want to save the polygons even after not saving it , and i have hided the save and cancel button.
Im already rendering the polygons using my own state and im changing it on every vertex change using editvertex , but when i switch to create polygon after editing, the changes that i have made is reverting back . its not actually changing my state back its showing some other internal state of react leaflet draw , when i rerender and come back again , the changes i have made is reflected.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
